# React useState Hook - Can't Clear State on Form Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Slightly novice react hooks user here.  Trying to submit a blog post form, consisting of a title, author and URL.  I can submit my form correctly and values are saving in database, but I can't clear the data from the form.

I'm holding state like this

```
  const [newBlog, setNewBlog] = useState({ url: "", author: "", title: "" });
```

and handling form change to update state like this:

```
  const handleBlogChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setNewBlog({ ...newBlog, [name]: value });
  };
```

example setup of one my input fields (identical across all three)

```
 <form className="form" onSubmit={addBlog}>
<div className="col-lg-9">
                    <input
                      className="form-control"
                      id="title"
                      aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                      placeholder="Enter title"
                      name="title"
                      value={newBlog.title}
                      onChange={handleBlogChange}
                    />
                  </div>
```

and this is my addBlog function. you can see where I commented out one version of clearing the state which is causing problems.

```
const addBlog = event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const { url, title, author } = newBlog;

    const blogObject = {
      url,
      title,
      author
    };

    blogService
      .create(blogObject)
      .then(data => {
        setBlogs(blogs.concat(data));
        showMessage(`Success! ${newBlog.title} by ${newBlog.author} was added`);
        // setNewBlog([...newBlog, { url: "", title: "", author: "" }]);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        showMessage(
          `Sorry can't add blog. Here's why: ${error.response.data.error}`,
          false
        );
      });
  };
```

I've also tried different variations which are leaving the data in the form, no errors, but not clearing out the form.  Examples of this include

```
setNewBlog(''), setNewBlog([]) and 
setNewBlog(newBlog.title='')
```

Nothing is working.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the new blog state to be something different than what you had when you started? why not `setNewBlog({ url: "", author: "", title: "" })`?

Comment: It would be better to use it this way. 
setBlogs ((prevBlogsState) => {... prevBlogsState, data});

if you want to keep prev new blog url you can do this;

setNewBlog  ((prevNewBlogState) => {... prevNewBlogState, title:"", author: "" });

Comment: thanks guys, @azium that worked perfect, think i had been staring at this too long.